# How to make GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette's PaletteView visible on first start

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-gef

My GEF editor (extending `GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette`) always opens the editor with the palette *hidden* on *first start* of the application / first opening of the editor (after a build for example).

As this will potentially bewilder users who'll need to go in search of the flyout icon first, I'd like to have the palette view shown whenever the editor is opened. The user can then choose to close it on his/her preferences.

How can I achieve this? The API doesn't seem to give any clues, or I'm unable to find them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The state of the palette defines if it is open or closed. This state is accessible using the `getPalettePreferences().setPaletteState()` method that is accessible in the `GraphicalEditorWithFlyoutPalette`. To open the palette, you must set it to the `FlyoutPaletteComposite.STATE_PINNED_OPEN`, like this:

```
getPalettePreferences().setPaletteState(FlyoutPaletteComposite.STATE_PINNED_OPEN);
```

If you want to **ALWAYS** override the state so that the palette is always opened with the editor, you have to add the line to the constructor of your editor. If you only want to do this once, and then leave the state as it was last selected by the user... No idea how to do this :-(

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I had found the same thing browsing the plugin sources as well ;). It's fine to make the open palette default behaviour, no state memory needed as of now. Guess you could introduce logging for startups to trigger this only at first start, but that's a bit over the top for my use case.